# How do I use a variable that calls a method in the method its self?

Tags: java

I'm just wondering how to use the variable that calls a method in the method itself. for example if i had a method public void addTwo, which adds 2 to the variable that calls it, how do i use the variable that calls it in the code to add 2 to it?

```
public void addTwo(){
     //add two to the variable that calls
     //This is where i need help
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = 3;
    x.addTwo();
    S.O.P(x);
}
```

it would print 5

Comment: You can't call invoke a method on a primitive type; it isn't a reference type.

Comment: For that reason, the simple answer is 'you don't'. You can't just make up arbitrary code and wonder why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to go in this direction but I suggest you to avoid it.

The notation x.y() is used to call the method y of object x.If you declare x as int, it will a primitive type and as such will not have any personalized methods.

What you can do is create a new class with personalized methods that embeds an integer inside:

```
public class StackOverflowInt{
  private int x;

  public StackOverflowInt(int value) {
    this.x = value;
  }

  public int addTwo(){
    return this.x+2;
  }
}
```

and then use this class to achieve your result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackOverflowInt integer = new StackOverflowInt(3);
    System.out.println(integer.addTwo());
}
```

this will print 5.

Another alternative implementation is the following:

```
public class StackOverflowInt{
private int x;

public StackOverflowInt(int value) {
    this.x = value;
}

public void addTwo(){
    this.x = this.x+2;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.valueOf(x);
}
}
```

and then:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     StackOverflowInt integer = new StackOverflowInt(3);
     integer.addTwo();
     System.out.println(integer); //prints 5
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do here is this:

```
public static int addTwo(int x){
     return x + 2;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = 3;
    x = addTwo(x);
    S.O.P(x);
}
```

You can only call a method by an instance (e.g. `x.addTwo()`) if it belongs to instance's class and/or is accessible. As `x` is of primitive type (and not class), you can't do `x.addTwo()`.

Answer (score 0):

As @ElliottFrisch mentioned you cannot call a method on a primitive data type. From what it looks like you're trying to do, you need to make your "addTwo" method take and return an int like so.

```
public static int addTwo(int n) {
  return n + 2;
}
```

and then assign the result to your variable x

```
int x = 1;
x = addTwo(x);
```

Comment: "Alternately you could extend the Int class as opposed to the primitive data type int." can you clarify this?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel disregard that - I was thinking about Swift, edited the answer, thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

In Java int is a primitive type, not an object. So, you can't write `x.addTwo()`
Probably the following class will suit you:

```
public class MyInt {
    private int value;

    public MyInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void addTwo() {
        value += 2;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it as follows:

```
x = new MyInt(3);
x.addTwo();
System.out.println(x.getValue());
```